# How to pass confirmation password validation

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I got two password fields at my JSF - and error messages for them, so if confirmation password is not equal to defining password - err message should appears on the screen. But it also appears even if fields are equals but defining password not passed validation (so it passed to confirmation password validator as null)

so - this is my defining password JSF snippet

```
 <div class="item"
 style="height: initial">
 <p:outputLabel id="l_passDef" for="passDef"
 value="#{msgs['customerForm.defaultPassword']}"/>
<p:password id="passDef" widgetVar="passDefVar" value="#{customerBean.customer.password}"
feedback="true" label="Default Password"
redisplay="true" required="true"
requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.passDef.mandatory']}"
validatorMessage="#{msgs['Error.passDef.wrongFormat']}"
                                                binding="#{passDef}">
<p:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="hideCustomerErrMsg('passDef')"/>
<f:validateRegex pattern="(?=.{8,})((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])).*"/>
</p:password>
<div class="pass-message">
<p:message id="m_passDef" for="passDef" display="text"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

so - this is my confirmation password JSF snippet

```
<div class="item">
<p:outputLabel id="l_passConf" for="passConf"
value="#{msgs['customerForm.confirmPassword']}"/>
<p:password id="passConf" widgetVar="passConfVar" value="#{customerBean.customer.password}"
label="Confirm Password" redisplay="true" required="true"
requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.passConf.mandatory']}"
                                                >
<f:attribute value="#{passDef}" name="passDef"/>
<f:validator binding="#{confirmPasswordValidator}"/>
<p:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="hideCustomerErrMsg('passConf')"/>
</p:password>
<div class="pass-message">
<p:message id="m_passConf" for="passConf" display="text"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

and this is my validator

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class ConfirmPasswordValidator implements Validator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ConfirmPasswordValidator.class);

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("messages/messages_en");
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
        UIInput uiInput = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("passDef");
        String defaultPassword = (String) uiInput.getValue();
        String confirmPassword = (String) value;

        if ((!confirmPassword.equals(defaultPassword))&&(defaultPassword != null)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "",
                    resourceBundle.getString("Error.passConf.confirm")));
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me how to hide err message if password fields are equal but first (defining) password field not passed validation

Comment: Look at the showcase... PF password has 'matching' built in https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml

Comment: Thanks - but it is not working on the second password field((

Comment: It works in the showcase... find the differences with what you tried

Comment: As I tried it is works only if it is used on the first password field not second

Comment: comparing passwords works... you tried 'it' and 'it' only works... what is 'it'... please show code....  ypu seem to be trying to implement something that works out of the box

Comment: it - I mean "Check" at the second field